# C++ code and C version macros

Tags: c++, c

This is expected to be a too specific question. That's probably because I lack some basic knowledge that I can't find by googling. Feel free to answer a more general version of the question if that makes more sense.

Given some C++ code, I would like to know whether (and then how) its specific standards version, and its C standards version (if any) correlate.

I have verfied that this test code

```
#include <cstdio>
int main(void)
{
    printf("%ld\n", _POSIX_C_SOURCE);
    return 0;
}
```

prints "200809" when compiled with any of "g++ -std=c++98", "g++ -std=c++11", "clang++ -std=c++98", "clang++ -std=c++11".

(When I compile C with any explicit standards version, the _POSIX_C_SOURCE macro isn't defined at all).

Why is that? What doesn't make sense at all is that compiling C++98 effects in _POSIX_C_SOURCE being 200809 (that is, 10 years *later*).

Comment: May be it is because of some compiler extension!

Comment: The `_GNU_SOURCE`, `_BSD_SOURCE`, `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` etc. macros are set by the program being compiled rather than the compiler environment. Setting them from a C++ include file is kind of a bug, although the standard library authors probably found it necessary for some `inline` functions to work.

Comment: @SimonRichter: Good point. What initially lead me to this question was wanting to set `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` to get `getchar_unlocked()`. So is the acceptable method to first include C++ headers, then redefine _POSIX_C_SOURCE, then include C headers?

Comment: @JoSo: What environment are you currently compiling under that you are able to get no _POSIX_C_SOURCE when compiling C code? Under normal circumstances, to get `getchar_unlocked()`, you use a new enough glibc and do `#include <stdio.h>`.

Comment: @shart: I don't get _POSIX_C_SOURCE when I either give `-ansi` or an explicit `-std=cXX` (checked `89`/`90`,`99`, and `11`), whether it's `clang` or `gcc`. I have a standard Debian wheezy amd64.

Comment: (But as stated in the question, when it's C++ instead of C, I get _POSIX_C_SOURCE automatically, and that felt like a bug to me just as SimonRichter said).

Comment: @JoSo: I'd recommend compiling with `-std=gnu99` for C code.

Comment: @JoSo, the feature declaration macros must always come before the first include file. The C++ headers need to be able to deal with the macro being defined beforehand.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's two things that you might be looking for:

- If you want to detect C++98: The macro `__cplusplus` is defined to be `199711L`.
- If you want to detect C++11: The macro `__cplusplus` is defined to be `201103L`.

If you'd like to detect compiler versions, this site has a ton of information about the various macros that apply: http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Compilers/

As to `_POSIX_C_SOURCE`, this is a attribute of the features available in the **C Standard Library**. So because you are using a new glibc (atleast 2.10), you are able to support these features.

As to the C compiler not reporting these values, you may need to explicitly include `<features.h>` to access them.

Comment: Does this mean the _POSIX_C_SOURCE macro and what I set via `-std=XXX` (whether C or C++) are completely orthogonal things?

Answer (score 7):

Well I think that's because _POSIX_C_SOURCE does not relate to any C++ standard spec, but to POSIX specs:

```
_POSIX_C_SOURCE
          Defining this macro causes header files to expose definitions
          as follows:

          ·  The value 1 exposes definitions conforming to POSIX.1-1990
             and ISO C (1990).

          ·  The value 2 or greater additionally exposes definitions for
             POSIX.2-1992.

          ·  The value 199309L or greater additionally exposes
             definitions for POSIX.1b (real-time extensions).

          ·  The value 199506L or greater additionally exposes
             definitions for POSIX.1c (threads).

          ·  (Since glibc 2.3.3) The value 200112L or greater exposes
             definitions corresponding to the POSIX.1-2001 base
             specification (excluding the XSI extension).

          ·  (Since glibc 2.10) The value 200809L or greater exposes
             definitions corresponding to the POSIX.1-2008 base
             specification (excluding the XSI extension).
```

The value you get is the default value supported by the compiler/libs you use.

Answer (score 0):

_POSIX_C_SOURCE may be a compiler extension.

It is a POSIX spec, not a C++ spec.

so some compiler won't support it.